# Can a port be scanned when behind a router?

Tags: port

This article describes websites are scanning ports of visitors:
https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2020/05/websites_conduc.html

The question is, how is it possible for these sites to scan the ports if the visitor is behind a NAT?

Comment: No, to scan computer behind it mean your PC is in a DMZ or with port redirect. To note a site running on your PC in a browser with module (ie; javascript) could potentially scan what run, but it’s because you runned the site module, like hp or dell do, as with an activex module they can see your warrenty status and such detail

Answer (score 1):

Yes Portscanning is possible across multiple collision domains.

From a comment below it seems as this Question is in relation to scanning behind NAT. Which is best Answerd under: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/140544/scan-a-computer-behind-nat

Comment: How does the portscan get through the nat?

Comment: You did not mention NAT at all in your Original Question.

Comment: I tried to answer according to NAT. Please adapt your question accordingly,

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: so behind a NAT its almost possible to scan for ports in general, right?